# Does display flex properties work for inner element's just like parent elements

Tags: html, flexbox, grid

As i learned the display:flex; will work only for the **container(parent)** but in the code below when i use flex box properties in **child(items)** such as **align-items, justify-contents** why the child (item) elemnts start to move.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT6ze.jpg)

```
**internal css styling **

 .container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  gap: 3rem;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1.5fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}
.item {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(105, 49, 158);
  **display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

**body part**
  <div class="container">
<div class="item cowboy">1</div>
<div class="item astronaut">2</div>
<div class="item book">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

flex doesnt work with parent containers only,and if i understood your intention
this line   **grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1.5fr;** has an impact on the width of the items making the first 2 items have equal size and the last one occupy more space making it appear to move to the right side

if you want the boxes to be aligned equally in the parent container try this snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%; 
}

.item {
  width:5em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #0076ff; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```